# What are the defaults for gensim's fasttext?

Tags: gensim, fasttext

I cannot find anything about the default values about the parameters for gensim fasttext [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastText)

Or are they the same as for the original Facebook fasttext implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very link in your question, https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastText, shows all the defaults right there. To excerpt it here:

```
class gensim.models.fasttext.FastText(sentences=None, corpus_file=None, 
    sg=0, hs=0, size=100, alpha=0.025, window=5, min_count=5, 
    max_vocab_size=None, word_ngrams=1, sample=0.001, seed=1, workers=3, 
    min_alpha=0.0001, negative=5, ns_exponent=0.75, cbow_mean=1, 
    hashfxn=<built-in function hash>, iter=5, null_word=0, min_n=3, 
    max_n=6, sorted_vocab=1, bucket=2000000, trim_rule=None, 
    batch_words=10000, callbacks=(), compatible_hash=True)
```

Those that are for the corresponding parameter to the Facebook native FastText probably *should* have the same defaults, but it's possible that some have varied slightly to match analogous parameters in other gensim classses. So, if you were counting on identical defaults for some analysis, you should check these values against the Facebook docs.